# Ubuntu 14.04 causes SSH error, but not Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have two different servers, one has ubuntu 12.10, the other has ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I need to SSH files to a 3rd remote server. The 14.04 LTS server throws an error when attempting to SSH.

This is the log of 14.04 in verbose mode:

```
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to domain.com [207.207.207.207] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHD
debug1: no match: SSHD
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
Write failed: Broken pipe
lost connection
```

This is the log of the SSH for 12.10 in verbose mode:

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1.2, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to domain.com [207.207.207.207] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHD
debug1: no match: SSHD
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ae:ae:ae:ae:dc:3e:7a:ac:6e:dc:dc:85:fa:66:8e:hi
debug1: Host 'domain.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
This system is for the use of authorized users only. Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in excess of their authority, may be subject to punitive actions
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password Authentication
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to domain.com ([207.207.207.207]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

Because of the `write | broken pipe` error, I added the following options to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes 
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

However error still persists. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Also, this might be related to using SSH with passphrase instead of a standard public key.

Comment: Sorry, I might not be using the right terminology. These are fresh installs from scratch. So right now I have two servers, one running 12.10 where `ssh` works, and 14.04 LTS where `ssh` does not work. Not sure how to diagnose the underlying problem from this point. I'll edit the question to make it more accurate.

Comment: I have different questions.  From your 14.04 system have you ruled out any issues at lower layers?  Can you ping remote system from the 14.04 box?  Can you ping the 14.04 system from the remote side?  If you run tcpdump on the remote end do you see the incoming ssh connection?  Do you see any errors in your log on the remote?

Comment: Have not ruled out lower layer issues. I don't have full access to the remote server, so I can't see the remote server's logs. Connection is established in the ssh logs. Ping attempts result in timeout (for both 12.10 and 14.04LTS).

Comment: Also related http://serverfault.com/questions/619458/group-of-workstations-refuse-to-ssh-to-one-another-but-can-connect-just-fine-in/619465

Comment: If the two links above do not help, then we'll need to see a packet capture or logs from the server. Having packet captures from both the client and the server would be ideal, but having just one of the two may still provide answers.

Comment: If you install Ubuntu 12.10 on the server that currently has 14.04 does ssh then work?